# phpmyadmin on Oracle Linux Server

Tags: linux, oracle, phpmyadmin

I'm a newbie in the open source world. Always used to paying i can't imagine we can get a whole OS for free!!! None the less from reputed companies like Oracle, i'm sold! OK so i got Oracle Linux server 6.1 installed and its running fine. I also checked all the boxes under webserver and MySQl during installation and i can see the Apache home page when i type localhost on the browser and i have started both the Apache & the MySql services.

My question: is there a GUI based admin tool like phpmyadmin to administer the MySql DB which is already installed? If not can someone point me to a step by step guide for the same. I have been trying since last 4 days and i just can't understand how to do this and what is required? I also saw some post saying something like Oracle Enterprise Manager is available through which we can administer the DB but i just can't find out how to get to the console? Is there a locahost url or something to get it to work?

Finally all i want to do is run Drupal on the Linux server and be able to administer the DB with phpmyadmin, if everything is complicated can i just install LAMP or XXAMP which will give me everything i need in one go. Although i feel since Apache & MySQL is already installed when i installed the OS not sure what will happen.

I know i'm all over the place, making the transition from Windows and am really new to this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
KK

Comment: May be Oracle management pack for Oracle linux  might be useful http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/oem/grid-control/omp-linux-091367.html

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Enterprise Linux is based off of the Red Hat sources, just like CentOS.

Found [a link](http://pritisolanki.wordpress.com/2012/01/10/install-phpmyadmin-on-centos-6/) on how to get it setup with CentOS 6, which should work for OEL.

Comment: Thanks, i have already tried it but it's still not working. Does oracle Linux not come with any built in interfaces? I ask because when I'm installing Linux it gives me all these great options of installing MySQL and Apache, I'm surprised they have not added any GUI interface along with it. Thanks again though for the answer. Also would installing something like xxamp be more easy?

Comment: For the most part, server administration is not done with a GUI, even an ncurses one. It's going to be pretty rare finding a server that installs that by default and, if it does, you don't want it.

I'd definitely try out something like Ubuntu Server 12.04 if you're new Linux administration. Or, if you need to be RHEL-like, CentOS. There is great documentation for both.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately i'm stuck with Oracle linux enterperise server 6.1 as that is the client requirement. Where would be the best place to look for information for Oracle-PhpmyAdmin ? I have searched every where including Oracle site but no one has any informaiton. Thanks again. KK